# How could I query my windows application from a website

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, communication, communication-protocol

I'm trying to figure something out regarding how I can create communication between 2 machines using the internet as the communication line.

**Idea**

I would like to have a windows service/application that know how to talk to a web site for the first place (that's easy) but since that time, **the web site should query that machine and ask information**.

**Scenario**

Let's imagine that I install this application on my machine, I set up where and how I have my local database and now I want to be able to use a webpage to query that database.

**Protocols**

I'm trying to figure it out the [PPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol) (Point-to-Point) protocol and the idea is something that we regularly use with torrents... but I can't find any information on this under .NET

**Propose**

**The main propose for all of this** is to make it easy to persons install this application (mainly a Web Service) but to avoid teach them how to set up a domain name to point to their server, as well figuring out how to get the endpoint of the just-installed web service... I would like to "*Hey, please install and set your credentials, let the configuration with me*"

Is there any library that I can use to create such environment?

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want a webservice?

Comment: the idea is to have the webservice, but in a way that persons don't need to know how to change DNS to point a domain name to their own machine and to be able to work under a NAT server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the peer-to-peer api in .net?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.peertopeer.aspx